# Ignore an approval step for a certain branch CCI 2.0

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

What I want by default is for my branch to build, then wait for approval to deploy to dev. However, if I push to the dev branch, that should deploy without approval.

I have the following workflow:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
      - approve-dev:
          type: approval
          requires:
              - build
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore: dev
      - deploy-dev:
          requires:
            - approve-dev
```

The problem is that when the `approve-dev` job is skipped, the `deploy-dev` job loses its requirement, so the only possible step is `build`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you try having `deploy-dev` also require `build`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an `AND` rather than an `OR`, so that would just mean it would never work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out a way to do this, but it's quite verbose, basically you duplicate the workflow at that point, with one copy only for that branch, and one copy which ignores that branch, like so:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
      - approve-dev:
          type: approval
          requires:
              - build
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore: dev
      - deploy-dev:
          requires:
            - approve-dev
      - deploy-dev-auto:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: dev
```

Using templates (`<<deploy-dev-defaults: &deploy-dev-defaults`) to define the tasks means you don't have to rewrite the job, just specify it twice with the two different names.